# Why is an entire string being read and printed with getchar?

Tags: c, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char c = getchar();
while ( c != '.')
{
putchar(c);
c = getchar();
}
}
```

when you run above code and input any string like "Shubham jain". the whole string gets copied and gets printed while `getchar()` should have read only the first character from the string. can someone explain how is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you input a string using your program, it will automatically provide input for every char in the string on `getchar` function, calling it multiple times. The moment the loop detects a '.' the program stops reading any more characters.

Comment: If you think this is the right answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

so input string is buffered and when getchar() is called the next time, it doesn't wait again for the user to enter a new character and rather takes it from the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` isn't `char` its actually `int`. normally you can store what you entered into `getchar` into an integer and cast it into a char. Now, why it read everything? `getchar doesn't have a specific size that it reads but that has to do more with the`EOF`. use`getc` to read single characters.